# Using LDAP/Active Directory with PIN based authentication

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

We'd like to integrate our service with LDAP, but because of hardware constraints,
we're only allow 4 digit user ids and passwords.

What would be the best practice for performing such an authetication?

We've considered adding User ID and PIN attributes to the LDAP user schema, but we're not sure how happy people would be with modifying their schema to interact with our service.
The PIN attribute would have to have the same support that native user passwords have. (hashing and salting etc.)

**UPDATE**

Another consideration is how ldap_bind works with this scenario. How do we get it to use an alternate authentication method? Can this even be done without affecting other services that use the same LDAP server?

Comment: are the user ids AND the passwords both 4 digits?

Comment: Yes, Unfortunately.

Comment: The User ID and the password, Not sure how that would work with password which would need to be salted and hashed

Comment: could you not just use the existing username / password fields in the directory? assuming you control the creation of the users you can enforce they meet your digits rule. that way passwords will be salted/hashed and no-one will have to do anything weird to bind against your directory.

Comment: But the LDAP Service may be run by the client, where we don't have control of the creation of users. They'd use the same user credentials for other services eg: Windows login, Corporate Intranet. In that case 4 digit passwords would be ridiculus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoudn't modify the LDAP User Schema, but create your own schema definition under `/etc/openldap/schema/yourservice.schema`.

You should get an unique OID for your org using [this form at IANA](http://www.iana.org/cgi-bin/enterprise.pl)
For the syntax attribute, remember that numeric strings have an OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.36 and that if you add a limit value, it's a lower bound not a limit.

Comment: OK... that sound like what I want. But what about authenticating using the PIN, It's no-standard attribute, so how do I get ldap_bind to use that?